# Firebase Unity Google-services-info.plist iOS not working

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, info.plist

I'm trying to use Firebase in my unity project for IOS I imported the plist file but when I run the program I get the following error

Unable to load options for default app ([/Users/.../ Coding AR Demo/Assets/StreamingAssets/google-services-desktop.json, /Users/.../Assets/StreamingAssets/google-services.json] are missing or malformed)

Firebase app creation failed.
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy)
Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create ()

Has anyone had a similar problem I'm not sure if I'm importing the file wrong it just says to drag it in the main assets folder

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by also importing the android setting, that is google-services.json in a folder named streaming assets

That seemed to fix it

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today. In my case, I solved this issue by placing both `google-services.json` and `Google-services-info.plist` in `Assets > StreamingAssets` under my project directory, so Firebase was able to autoconfigure. I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I created StreamingAssets folder in the Assests folder and copied the google-service.json file into that folder. then it was fixed